# Lock control to screen location

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form with a Dock = Filled picture box control in it.  When I resize the form's bottom or right edges, the amount of visible picture increases or decreases, but the picture's screen space coordinates remain constant.  However when I resize the top or left edges of the form, the picture's image moves so that its top left edge matches the top left edge of the form.

That is, when I resize the form's left or top edges, the picture moves.  This behavior makes sense for a lot of cases, and I understand why it's the default, but for my case I'd prefer if it worked like the bottom and right edges where the screen space coordinates of the image remain fixed and only more or less of it is revealed as the form is resized.

In pictures, this is the original form:

[image: Original form]

This is when it's resized by dragging the bottom right corner:

[image: bottom right dragged form]

That's also what it looks like when you drag the top left corner, but in that case it's sort of dragging the picture along with it, so the picture's top left corner is always flush with the form's top left corner.  But I'd rather it looked something like this mockup instead:

[image: desired behavior mock up]

So that the picture is essentially "fixed" in screen space and resizing the form just reveals more or less of it.

I tried something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Point originalScreenSpace;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Shown += Form1_Shown;
        Resize += Form1_Resize;
    }

    void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        originalScreenSpace = PointToScreen(pictureBox1.Location);
    }

    private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var newLoc = PointToScreen(pictureBox1.Location);
        var deltaX = newLoc.X - originalScreenSpace.X;
        var deltaY = newLoc.Y - originalScreenSpace.Y;

        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(-deltaX, -deltaY);
    }
}
```

But unsurprisingly the results don't seem quite right (the image's screen space coordinates still drift) and it's far from smooth.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the `Dock` property. Instead position the `PictureBox` on the form and size it as appropriate. Then set its `Anchor` to `None`.

Comment: This is close but not quite working right: when I resize the form it seems to be splitting the difference between moving the pictureBox and not.  That is, if I resize the form to add (100,100) to its size (from any direction), it moves the image (50,50).  I'd expect it to either not move the image at all or move it the full 100 units in a direction depending on which side I'm dragging.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the Location(0, 0) and Dock the control to Left, Top:

```
pictureBox1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)));
pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
```

and do not alter the Location in `Form1_Resize` event.

Comment: This doesn't work: I end up with the same sort of behavior I have when the control is docked: it does what I want when I resize the bottom or right edges, but moves the image when I resize the top or left edges.

Comment: Did you remove your resize event?

Comment: Yes.  Does it work on your machine?  If so, what version of VS are you using?

Comment: Yes it works, its VS 2013 .net 4.5 but it doesn't matter. It is same in all frameworks. Where did you put the code I gave to you?

Comment: In the form's constructor, after InitializeComponents().  Are you sure it works on your machine like I described I want?  Even conceptually, setting the anchor should just lock the image to the top left of the form and never let there be any empty space between the top left of the form's client area and the top left corner of the image.  That is, it should "anchor" the top left corner of the image to the top left corner of the form, dragging the image around as you resize the top or left edges, right?